# Discount is applying on wrong categories

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0, catalog-price-rules, cart-rule

I have set shopping cart price rule for applying wholesale discount on certain categories by setting categories IDs when subtotal matches certain boundary; but I am facing an issue that some categories are getting discount although they are not included in the category id list.

Kindly check my current discount rule setting in the image below.

[image]

I have set the `Stop Further Rules Processing` to `Yes`.

Not getting why this behaving like this. Any one having any idea about?

Comment: I have tried diabling all other rules and delete the conditions for just one rule but this is also applying discount, i have deleted the cache too.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule says that

> If an item is found in the cart

Ie. If any item in the cart is in one of those categories - then the rule applies.

You need to add an action to only apply discount to products that are in that specific category, otherwise it will apply to the whole cart.

[image]

Comment: Actually the product was getting discount becase it was present in other categories which are set on discount, and now i have changed the concept i want to apply discount on higest price on the cart. Do you have any idea for this.

Comment: so you want to give the discount on highest product price from whole cart right? If YES then you need some customization because this functionality is not available in Magento.